# What is the source of 2 Timothy 2:11-13?

Tags: 2-timothy

New International Version
2 Timothy 2:

```
 11 Here is a trustworthy saying:
     If we died with him,
       we will also live with him; 
     12 if we endure,
       we will also reign with him.
     If we disown him,
       he will also disown us;
     13if we are faithless,
       he remains faithful,
       for he cannot disown himself.
```

Had Paul read this from somewhere?

At least part of it is similar to
Matthew 10:33

> But whoever disowns me before others, I will disown before my Father in heaven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paul often quoted "trustworthy sayings".  Here is a sample:

- 1 Tim 1:15 - **Here is a trustworthy** saying that deserves full acceptance: Christ Jesus came into the world to save sinners--of whom I am the worst.
- 1 Tim 3:1 - **Here is a trustworthy saying**: Whoever aspires to be an overseer desires a noble task.
- 1 Tim 4:8, 9 - For physical exercise is of limited value, but godliness is valuable in every way, holding promise for the present life and for the one to come. **This is a trustworthy saying**, worthy of full acceptance.
- 2 Tim 2:11-13 - **This is a trustworthy saying**: If we died with Him, we will also live with Him; if we endure, we will also reign with Him; if we deny Him, He will also deny us; if we are faithless, He remains faithful, for He cannot deny Himself.
- Titus 3:4-8 - But when the kindness of God our Savior and His love for mankind appeared, He saved us, not by the righteous deeds we had done, but according to His mercy, through the washing of new birth and renewal by the Holy Spirit. This is the Spirit He poured out on us abundantly through Jesus Christ our Savior, so that, having been justified by His grace, we would become heirs with the hope of eternal life. **This saying is trustworthy**. And I want you to emphasize these things ...

Note that in some cases, Paul creates the saying himself and in other cases there appears to be be an allusion to some of Jesus' teaching.  In other cases, perhaps Paul quoted an early Christian hymn.  We do not know.  in the case of 2 Tim 2:11-13, the Cambridge commentary observes:

> We cannot say for certain whether the sentences following are really
> strophes from a Christian hymn (Münter, Ueber die älteste christliche
> Poesie, p. 29, and Paulus, Memorabilia, i. 109) or not; still it is
> not improbable that they are, all the more that the same may be said
> of 1 Timothy 3:16.

Answer (score 2):

**What is the source of 2 Timothy 2:11-13?**

11 Here is a trustworthy saying:  we died with him,  we will also live with him;  12 if we endure,   we will also reign with him.  If we disown him,  he will also disown us;  13if we are faithless,   he remains faithful,  for he cannot disown himself.

Had Paul read this from somewhere?

Romans 6:5,8  (NASB)for Vs11

> 5 For if we have become united with Him in the likeness of His death,
> certainly we shall also be in the likeness of His resurrection,
>
> 8 Now if we have died with Christ, we believe that we shall also live
> with Him,

Matthew 10:33(NASB) for Vs 12

> 33 But whoever denies Me before people, I will also deny him before My
> Father who is in heaven.

Luke 12:9 (NASB) for Vs 12

> 9 but the one who denies Me before people will be denied before the
> angels of God.

Psalm 51:4  (NASB) For Vs 13

> 4 Against You, You only, I have sinned   And done what is evil in Your
> sight,  So that You are justified when You speak  And blameless when
> You judge.